# Can't install peerflix server with npm on ubuntu18.04

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, ubuntu-18.04

I tried to install peerflix server to my server(ubuntu 18.04) remotely following the steps on https://github.com/asapach/peerflix-server and checked 9000 port but I couldn't get a response. I tried to rebuild npm, reinstall npm and nodejs but result was same. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. Adding firewall rule to allow to 9000 port is solving.